# How to add header or footer using itextpdf only after first page in java?

Tags: java, itext

I have written a java program to download a pdf , but I want to add header to that pdf document only after 1st page , I have tried some code.

```
class MyFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.BOLD);

    private void addHeader(PdfWriter writer,Document document){
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        Phrase header = new Phrase("Customer Id : ", ffont);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                header,
                (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + 
                document.leftMargin(),
                document.top() - 10, 0);

    }

     private void addFooter(PdfWriter writer,Document document){
         PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
            Phrase footer = new Phrase("Page "+writer.getPageNumber(), 
            ffont);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    footer,
                    (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + 
                    document.leftMargin(),
                    document.bottom() - 10, 0);
        }


    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        try{
            addHeader(writer,document);
            addFooter(writer,document);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The footer function is working properly , but I want the header function to print only after 1st page, so I tried using

```
if(writer.getPageNumber() > 1)
```

but this condition is not working

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (document.getPageNumber() > 1)
```

The page number in the writer is the page number of the PDF and will be there after writing the PDF.

Comment: This works. I use:  if (document.getPageNumber() == 1) return;

Answer (score 0):

Better to try this method

```
document.resetHeader();
```

after the execution of the first-page logic.

Comment: The OP clearly uses page events for creation of headers and footers. Your solution, on the other hand, only works for the ancient way of using the `HeaderFooter` class.